# Probably an '80s B-movie with a blond boy and an old man, who has to decide whether to stay or go with aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, b-movies

I was talking with a Danish guy, who is 24 years old. He said that when he was four or five years old (in the 2000s), he and his brothers saw a movie with a blond kid and an old man, who looked like Ernest Hemingway. He does not know if they were friends or related.

Apparently there were aliens in the movie, and the old man had to decide whether to stay or go with them.

It was not a comedy; it may have been a drama. And he thinks that maybe it was American, from the '80s, that you never actually see the aliens, and that the old man says "shut up!" a lot, but that may be a blurry memory from when he was a four-year-old child.

I thought it might be *Cocoon*, which has lots of old men, but it does not fit the blond boy description.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already but could you and this guy please take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? Every detail counts - the more info we have, the greater your chances of a successful ID :)

Comment: Hi @Jenayah! I will talk to him later through chat (7 hours of difference!) but definitely, I will edit as quickly as I can. Thanks!

Comment: It could possibly be the second cocoon movie, Cocoon: The Return. It has a child in it, although he is not blonde, and the boys grandfather that sort of look like Hemmingway is he shaved.

Comment: Barry is a little blond boy in "Close Encounters of the Third Kind" but one could hardly classify Richard Dreyfus' character as Hemingway-esque, though he does choose to leave w/ the aliens (spoiler alert? lol)

Comment: This was a year ago... this Christmas I travelled over there and we chatted with his brother. We found out which movie it is! It is an Italian movie called The Sheriff and the Satellite Kid. It is definitely a comedy smh. That is where he remembered incorrectly.

Comment: @F.Esq I'm going to post that as an answer. It would be nice if you could come back to accept.

Comment: I was going to suggest https://youtu.be/nswae1s320k?t=51 :-D

Answer (score 6):

According to a comment by the original querent, it's [*The Sheriff and the Satellite Kid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sheriff_and_the_Satellite_Kid), originally released as *[Uno sceriffo extraterrestre... poco extra e molto terrestre](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079859/)*.

[image: Front cover of The SHeriff and the Satellite Kid]

> One morning, the little town of Newnan, Georgia, is thrown into hysteria when a UFO is reported over the nearby lake; even the personnel from the nearby Air Force base is mobilized. The only one remaining untouched by this hubbub is Sheriff Hall (Spencer), the big and punchy keeper of the local law; indeed, he does not believe in aliens, especially since layabouts like Brennan (Joe Bugner) use the excitement to commit all sorts of mischief. Still, strange things begin to happen to some of the citizens who share his point of view: a barber's chair begins to spin rapidly around its axis – along with its customer – and an ice cream cart suddenly disgorges its entire load (and more) onto the street after the vendor makes a joke about the aliens being hungry for his ice cream.
>
> The same night, a blackout hits the city. Hall goes on patrol when his rheumatic deputy Allen (Luigi Bonos) calls him to retrieve a runaway boy. Arriving at the boy's favorite place, the local amusement park, Hall finds not one but two boys; one of them – wearing a silver spacesuit – turns out to be the runaway, the other (an apparent nine-year-old; Cary Guffey) perpetually introduces himself as H7-25, comes up with space-related terms like lightyears and spaceship, brandishes a strange device which makes all things around him go haywire, and even enables Brennan (who has been taken into custody) to escape on two occasions and Allen to (temporarily) overcome his rheumatism. Still, the sheriff is not convinced – not until the boy irradiates him with what he calls "bio-magnetic energy", enabling him to make a very big trout leap into his hands and a horse talk in English!

....

> Finally, while Hall and H7-25 camp out at Stone Mountain to await the arrival of the boy's pick-up, Briggs and his men manage to kidnap the boy and bring him to the base. The sheriff, however, manages to infiltrate the facility and gets the boy out. In a mass showdown at the local fire brigade hall, where a party was to be held, Briggs and his men get their share from the Sheriff Hall, the little alien and their friends. Later that night, a spaceship comes to pick up H7-25, and he and Hall part ways. But as Hall returns home, he suddenly finds H7-25 sitting in the back of his car – he has managed to get an additional period of leave on Earth to spend with his big friend.

### Trailer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out the 1980s film AURORA ENCOUNTER? It has a boy and an old man and possible UFO connection.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! Could you please [edit] in some more details as to why you believe this is what the OP is looking for?